# why are Nayanars associated with Shaiva Siddhanta?

Tags: shiva, shaiva-siddhanta, nayanar

Why are Nayanars associated with Shaiva Sidhhanta philosophy? Did they themselves say so? Were they initiated from Shaiva Siddhanta mutts?

Comment: What is the scriptural basis for this "Shaiva Siddhanta" philosophy? Is the term scriptural?

Comment: Just like the Sri Vaishnava sect is based on the Pancharatra Agamas and the poems of the Alwars, the Shaiva Siddhanta sect is based on the 28 Shaiva Agamas and the poems of Nayanmars.